# what is ELF - something line feed?

Tags: node.js

i'm getting this error in travis and i have no idea what it means:

```
/home/travis/.nvm/v0.11.13/bin/node:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ELF
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

it also doesn't work on my local OS X - it just stalls. what does this mean?

reference: https://travis-ci.org/normalize/shorthands.js/builds/32499909

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what happens is that somewhere in your code node binary is used with `require`, something like `require('/home/travis/.nvm/v0.11.13/bin/node')`. Since it's not a valid js file, it causes `SyntaxError`. `ELF` is just a part of the binary, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)