# invalid token ELF at the top of a Node.js file

Tags: node.js

I got this weird error:

```
/home/oleg/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ELF
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

I am on Ubuntu, can't figure out what's causing it. It's not showing up in the plaintext here but you can see more in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Kinda sucks that Node.js doesn't tell you which file failed to compile/load

Comment: Can this =>  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322061/what-is-elf-something-line-feed] help?

Comment: Is this solved? If yes what was the solution? IS the solution above mentioned question by @david-r?